# How to write a simple LLVM backend target?

Tags: llvm, llvm-codegen

I have read [this doc](https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html#assembly-printer) and first chapter of [this example](https://jonathan2251.github.io/lbd/index.html).

The doc and example are really good at helping me understanding backend of compiler and LLVM.

However, they still not answering the question of for adding a new target, what file (minimum) I need to modify and add, with the reasons of doing that.

In the example, it asked me to change bunch of llvm config files, while in the doc, it just ask me to add `lib/Target/<name of target>` and add config option `-DLLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=<name of target>` or add target name into `LLVM_ALL_TARGETS` in `llvm/CMakeLists.txt`.

It actually makes me confused of how to add a new target simple and clear.

Thus I would like to ask if anyone knows, thanks!!!

Comment: One does not often see the adjective 'simple' affixed to the noun 'compiler'.

Comment: What errors did you encounter while adding new target ? You should start by doing it step-by-step... take an avr or arm controller, add target by yourself. Follow the steps in the documents. I guarantee you will fail the first few times, but you will learn a lot. Keep cpu specification handy. Next you can go for GPU or APU or DSP.

Comment: @chiragpatel one of the big problems is that there are a lot of files to modify and add, and the content in the files are also massive. The document does not provide a clear explanation for them. One of the example will be what is `InstrItinClass`used for? It's an empty class and no documentation mentioned it.....